# How to replace string for large file in Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: sed, replace, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, large-data

I have a large file in Google Cloud Storage, e.g 100GB. What's the best practice to replace string for this file content?

One simple option is:

1. Create GCE with local SSD
2. Download to GCE
3. Run `sed -i 's/old/new/g'` filename
4. Upload back to GCS

Answer (score 1):

Buckets in GCS are not file systems, so technically you cannot edit them directly, your solution is the simplest I can think of.

Other options:
[Fuse](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse) or [Filestore](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/) for file system support.
[Rsync](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync) allows to sync a local directory with GCS buckets.

Otherwise you’ll have to download/upload to edit the files located in GCS (like your solution with a GCE VM instance).

Answer (score 0):

An other way is to use dataflow. But it's huge for simply update a field... Sallee thing for dataprep. The new datafusion is visual but use dataproc for execution, still overkill.

If your file is easily loadable in big query,. Load it, transform it and export the result to the same format in GCS...

Your solution is the best I think.